# Add div below another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I  have a requirement to add 5 divs one by one on each click of a div button. ( the new div should be added below the existing div)
I done the code, but the news ones are getting attached on the top of existing div. please help to correct this.
I have another button which removes the added divs one by one(new ones to be remove first) 
here is my code.

```
  <div class="clearFix"></div>
     <div id="containershowmore" >
        <div id="dragbtnmore" style="cursor: default;">Show more buttons</div>
        <div id="dragbtnless" style="cursor: default;">Show Fewer buttons</div>
    </div>

 <div class="toAdd" style="display:none;" >
                <div id="dragdashboardmain" style="cursor: pointer;">dash</div></div>
    <div class="toAdd" style="display:none;" >
        <div id="dragrcalendar" style="cursor: pointer;">Calendar</div></div>
    <div class="toAdd" style="display:none;">
        <div id="dragresourcelist" style="cursor: pointer;">Rlist</div></div>
    <div class="toAdd" style="display:none;">
        <div id="dragdailynotes" style="cursor: pointer;">D Notes</div></div>
    <div class="toAdd" style="display:none;">
        <div id="dragweeklynotes" style="cursor: pointer;">W Notes</div></div>
```

script:

```
$("#dragbtnmore").click(function () {
        $('.toAdd').each(function () {
            if ($(this).css('display') == 'none') {
                $(this).css('display', 'block');
                return false;
            }
        });
        var i = 0;
        $('.toAdd').each(function () {
            if ($(this).css('display') != 'none') {
                i++;
            }
        });
        if (i == 5)
            $('#dragbtnmore').click(function () { return false; });
    });
    $("#dragbtnless").click(function () {
        $('.toAdd').each(function () {
            if ($(this).css('display') == 'block') {
                $(this).css('display', 'none');
                return false;
            }
        });
        var i = 0;
        $('.toAdd').each(function () {
            if ($(this).css('display') != 'block') {
                i++;
            }
        });
        if (i == 5)
            $('#dragbtnless').click(function () { return false; });
        $('#dragbtnless').click(function () { return true; });
    });

    $("#containershowmore").mouseleave(function () {
        $(this).hide();
    });
    function showmore() {
        document.getElementById('containershowmore').style.display = "block";
    }
```

style:

```
#containershowmore
{
    margin-top: -75px;position: relative;margin-left: 160px;background-color: #b1dafb;z-index: 1;
width: 125px;
float: right;
padding-left: 5px;
}

.toAdd
{

background-color: blue;
margin-top: -55px;
position: relative;
margin-bottom: 14px;

}
```

[**I referred this Fiddle **](http://jsfiddle.net/SFRgz/)

**Solution: 
Thankyou Shivam Chopra for helping me . Thanks a TON!!  :)

for others, HEre is the solution**

```
jsfiddle.net/coolshivster/YvE5F/12
```

Comment: create a fiddle please

Comment: @Mohsen http://jsfiddle.net/SFRgz/ i refered this fiddle, please check it

Comment: what the hell!!!! you fiddle and posted codes in question is entirely different... what are you actulayy tryin to do ??? please post related codes only

Comment: i said i "REFERRED" it.take a look at this fiddle, jsfiddle.net/coolshivster/YvE5F

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove margin top from both the div.

```
   #containershowmore
{
position: relative;margin-left: 160px;background-color: #b1dafb;z-index: 1;
width: 125px;
    float:right;
padding-left: 5px;
}
#dragbtnmore{
    margin-bottom:10px;
    border:1px solid black;
}

.toAdd
{
height:20px;
    width:70px;
background-color: blue;
position: relative;
margin-bottom: 14px;

}
```

Then, it will work accordingly.
Here, the code : http://jsfiddle.net/coolshivster/YvE5F/

I have rewritten your code according to your requirement.
Some explanation about the code

- I have create a parent div element with id="Add-element" that covers every element which contains class .toAdd .
- Then I created data attribute for every div containing class .toAdd .
- Now, I display the element one by one. But after first element. Every other element will prepend on the parent div i.e., #Add-element class.

Now, the code which I have rewritten.
jsfiddle link : http://jsfiddle.net/YvE5F/10/

Comment: thankyou for your time to create the fiddle Shivam Chopra :)
I need dash to move down as the new div gets added. can you help me in this?

Comment: i need that margin top as a part of the design.  anything else can be done?

Comment: I have updated the answer with the new code inside the second link.
http://jsfiddle.net/coolshivster/YvE5F/9/
And now, there's no problem in using margin-top for your design.

Comment: Resolved the bug by changing JanaScript linked in jsFiddle.
link : http://jsfiddle.net/YvE5F/10/

Comment: Thankyou so so much for helping,you saving me.
sorry for bugging you again .  when i click show more the second time, dash button is missing, this happens on even clicks.. Please help in this.